# Gerrit- Git push Error (n/a (unpacker error)) while pushing to gerrit

Tags: git, github, push, gerrit

I'm android developer so I had setted up Gerrit Code Review and Github for my Team! So After lots of struggle i got my github projects added to gerrit and also got replication work, but i'm not able to push this one repo. All other repos get pushed fine.

I cloned my github repo and then added my ssh link of project of gerrit with `git remote add *` and then I typed `git push gerrit HEAD:refs/for/ics`  but i'm getting some unpack error

Here is the whole log:

```
keyur@keyur-Inspiron-N4010:~/android_device_lge_p350$ git push gerrit HEAD:refs/for/ics
Counting objects: 7, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5/5), 526 bytes, done.
Total 5 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
fatal: Unpack error, check server log  
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (3/3)
error: unpack failed: error Missing unknown c605ed77d4a43b8389c7bb544c3a5834cf0f64cf
To ssh://keyur2maru@review.pecancm.insomnia247.nl:6117/android_device_lge_p350.git
 ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/for/ics (n/a (unpacker error))
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://keyur2maru@review.pecancm.insomnia247.nl:6117/android_device_lge_p350.git'
keyur@keyur-Inspiron-N4010:~/android_device_lge_p350$
```

And it fails :( I'm able to commit on any other repos :( but not able to get this one work :(

My config file :

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = git@github.com:PecanCM/android_device_lge_p350.git
[branch "cm-10.1"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/cm-10.1
[remote "gerrit"]
    url = ssh://keyur2maru@review.pecancm.insomnia247.nl:6117/android_device_lge_p350.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/gerrit/*
[branch "ics"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/ics
```

My Github repo : https://github.com/PecanCM/android_device_lge_p350

My Gerrit Server : http://review.pecancm.insomnia247.nl

Comment: I'm not sure if it's [the same problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16586642/git-unpack-error-on-push-to-gerrit) but it sounds like it. Can you try downgrading git and pushing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git unpack error on push to gerrit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16586642/git-unpack-error-on-push-to-gerrit)

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the gerrit server, check whether you have granted enough permissions to the git folder of your gerrit.