# git error unpack failed missing blob on git review to gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit

Hey I keep getting these errors randomly with some of the work I am doing. Normally I will edit a repo after a code review and then run the following commands.

```
git add .
git commit --amend
git review
```

then I sometimes get this error

```
error: unpack failed: error Missing blob c7eb8a2bcbe57f7f134819fbe6e2975b04b2e548
fatal: Unpack error, check server log
To ssh://a.b@address.com:29418/wns/chef/splunk-hop
 ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/publish/develop (n/a (unpacker error))
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://a.b@address.com:29418/wns/chef/splunk-hop'
```

Any ideas? Is it something I am doing or is it the server I am pushing it to?

Comment: Did you commit involve deletion of a file?

Comment: @TimCastelijns no i did not delete anything

Comment: Is it possible someone else made a commit that deleted a file while you were amending your commit?

Comment: @TimCastelijns it does not look like anyone has done that.

Answer (score 15):

I had this problem today and tried all the suggestions. Finally the solution was very simple:

- Switch to another branch (e.g. develop).
- Pull from the remote repository
- Switch back to your new branch and push.

With any luck it'll work now.

Answer (score 10):

I just did a `git fetch` and pushed again. I ***think*** the GC collects it and a fetch will get it back.

Answer (score 0):

See [Tardyp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1171875/tardyp)'s answer here:
[**git unpack error on push to gerrit**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20329880/1390251)

If this does not match your case, the repository is probably corrupted.