# Git- Gerrit integration : Missing Delta Error

Tags: git, integration, gerrit

I am getting missing delta error while pushing second commit to gerrit. Following is the error:-

```
Command : git push localhost/test HEAD:refs/for/master

**Error message**
Counting objects: 15, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Writing objects: 100% (12/12), 9.59 KiB, done.
Total 12 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: unpack error Missing delta base cec79c0e85bb63c85a8ed8c8e8f4d5d9df945887
error: unpack failed: error Missing delta base cec79c0e85bb63c85a8ed8c8e8f4d5d9df945887
```

I followed this link ([git unpack error on push to gerrit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16586642/git-unpack-error-on-push-to-gerrit)) but unable to resolve issue. Please help if any have solution

Further analyzed in logs, i got following errors on different parts :

1. org.eclipse.jgit.errors.MissingObjectException: Missing unknown
2. Caused by: com.google.gerrit.server.patch.PatchSetInfoNotAvailableException: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.MissingObjectException: Missing unknown
3. ERROR com.google.gerrit.httpd.restapi.RestApiServlet : Error in GET

Additional, i upgraded my git version to 2.0.1.