# Git unpack error on push to SCM Manager

Tags: git, scmmanager

Several of our repositories have recently started throwing unpack errors on push:

```
Counting objects: 3, done.                                                
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.                                  
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.                                    
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 288 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.                 
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)                                     
error: unpack failed: error Short read of block.                          
To http://git:8080/scm/git/Sandbox                                   
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (n/a (unpacker error))              
error: failed to push some refs to 'http://git:8080/scm/git/Sandbox'
```

SCM Manager logs are showing an error that seems to match the above:

```
2016-02-24 17:54:39.483 [qtp1967563673-16] ERROR org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.ObjectDirectory - ERROR: Exception caught while accessing pack file /var/lib/scm/repositories/git/Sandbox/objects/pack/pack-00aca3dbe856f7f3f7e730a00a1dae29aa7f8070.pack, the pack file might be corrupt
java.io.EOFException: Short compressed stream at 533
at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.PackFile.decompress(PackFile.java:341) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-3.7.1.201504261725-r-scm1.jar:3.7.1.201504261725-r-scm1]
at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.PackFile.load(PackFile.java:734) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-3.7.1.201504261725-r-scm1.jar:3.7.1.201504261725-r-scm1]
at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.PackFile.get(PackFile.java:259) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-3.7.1.201504261725-r-scm1.jar:3.7.1.201504261725-r-scm1]
at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.ObjectDirectory.openPackedObject(ObjectDirectory.java:417) [org.eclipse.jgit-3.7.1.201504261725-r-scm1.jar:3.7.1.201504261725-r-scm1]
at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.ObjectDirectory.openPackedFromSelfOrAlternate(ObjectDirectory.java:386) [org.eclipse.jgit-3.7.1.201504261725-r-scm1.jar:3.7.1.201504261725-r-scm1]
at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.ObjectDirectory.openObject(ObjectDirectory.java:378) [org.eclipse.jgit-3.7.1.201504261725-r-scm1.jar:3.7.1.201504261725-r-scm1]
at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.WindowCursor.open(WindowCursor.java:145) [org.eclipse.jgit-3.7.1.201504261725-r-scm1.jar:3.7.1.201504261725-r-scm1]
at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.ObjectReader.open(ObjectReader.java:229) [org.eclipse.jgit-3.7.1.201504261725-r-scm1.jar:3.7.1.201504261725-r-scm1]
at org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.RevWalk.parseAny(RevWalk.java:840) [org.eclipse.jgit-3.7.1.201504261725-r-scm1.jar:3.7.1.201504261725-r-scm1]
at org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.RevWalk.parseTree(RevWalk.java:780) [org.eclipse.jgit-3.7.1.201504261725-r-scm1.jar:3.7.1.201504261725-r-scm1]
at sonia.scm.repository.spi.GitBrowseCommand.getResult(GitBrowseCommand.java:325) [scm-git-plugin-1.46.jar:na]
at sonia.scm.repository.spi.GitBrowseCommand.getBrowserResult(GitBrowseCommand.java:147) [scm-git-plugin-1.46.jar:na]
at sonia.scm.repository.api.BrowseCommandBuilder.getBrowserResult(BrowseCommandBuilder.java:174) [scm-core-1.46.jar:na]
at sonia.scm.api.rest.resources.RepositoryResource.getBrowserResult(RepositoryResource.java:564) [classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor79.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_09-icedtea]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) ~[na:1.7.0_09-icedtea]
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409) [jersey-servlet-1.19.jar:1.19]
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558) [jersey-servlet-1.19.jar:1.19]
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733) [jersey-servlet-1.19.jar:1.19]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820) [javax.servlet-2.5.0.v201103041518.jar:na]
at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doService(ServletDefinition.java:263) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.service(ServletDefinition.java:178) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.service(ManagedServletPipeline.java:91) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:62) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:168) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:168) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:168) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:168) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:168) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:168) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:168) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
at sonia.scm.filter.MDCFilter.doFilter(MDCFilter.java:96) [classes/:na]
at sonia.scm.web.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:102) [scm-core-1.46.jar:na]
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:163) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:168) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:168) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:168) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:168) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:168) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
at sonia.scm.filter.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:111) [classes/:na]
at sonia.scm.web.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:102) [scm-core-1.46.jar:na]
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:163) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:168) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
at sonia.scm.web.filter.BasicAuthenticationFilter.processRequest(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:423) [scm-core-1.46.jar:na]
at sonia.scm.web.filter.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:214) [scm-core-1.46.jar:na]
at sonia.scm.web.security.ApiBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(ApiBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:116) [classes/:na]
at sonia.scm.web.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:102) [scm-core-1.46.jar:na]
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:163) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
at sonia.scm.filter.GZipFilter.doFilter(GZipFilter.java:112) [scm-core-1.46.jar:na]
at sonia.scm.web.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:102) [scm-core-1.46.jar:na]
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:163) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
at sonia.scm.web.filter.AutoLoginFilter.doFilter(AutoLoginFilter.java:87) [scm-core-1.46.jar:na]
at sonia.scm.web.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:102) [scm-core-1.46.jar:na]
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:163) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
at sonia.scm.filter.BaseUrlFilter.doFilter(BaseUrlFilter.java:117) [classes/:na]
at sonia.scm.web.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:102) [scm-core-1.46.jar:na]
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:163) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449) [shiro-web-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365) [shiro-web-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90) [shiro-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83) [shiro-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383) [shiro-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362) [shiro-web-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125) [shiro-web-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:163) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:118) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:113) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
at sonia.scm.boot.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:119) [classes/:na]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1288) [jetty-servlet-7.6.16.v20140903.jar:7.6.16.v20140903]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:443) [jetty-servlet-7.6.16.v20140903.jar:7.6.16.v20140903]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137) [jetty-server-7.6.16.v20140903.jar:7.6.16.v20140903]
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:556) [jetty-security-7.6.16.v20140903.jar:7.6.16.v20140903]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:227) [jetty-server-7.6.16.v20140903.jar:7.6.16.v20140903]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1044) [jetty-server-7.6.16.v20140903.jar:7.6.16.v20140903]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:372) [jetty-servlet-7.6.16.v20140903.jar:7.6.16.v20140903]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:189) [jetty-server-7.6.16.v20140903.jar:7.6.16.v20140903]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:978) [jetty-server-7.6.16.v20140903.jar:7.6.16.v20140903]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135) [jetty-server-7.6.16.v20140903.jar:7.6.16.v20140903]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154) [jetty-server-7.6.16.v20140903.jar:7.6.16.v20140903]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116) [jetty-server-7.6.16.v20140903.jar:7.6.16.v20140903]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:369) [jetty-server-7.6.16.v20140903.jar:7.6.16.v20140903]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:486) [jetty-server-7.6.16.v20140903.jar:7.6.16.v20140903]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:933) [jetty-server-7.6.16.v20140903.jar:7.6.16.v20140903]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:995) [jetty-server-7.6.16.v20140903.jar:7.6.16.v20140903]
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644) [jetty-http-7.6.16.v20140903.jar:7.6.16.v20140903]
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235) [jetty-http-7.6.16.v20140903.jar:7.6.16.v20140903]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82) [jetty-server-7.6.16.v20140903.jar:7.6.16.v20140903]
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:667) [jetty-io-7.6.16.v20140903.jar:7.6.16.v20140903]
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52) [jetty-io-7.6.16.v20140903.jar:7.6.16.v20140903]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608) [jetty-util-7.6.16.v20140903.jar:7.6.16.v20140903]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543) [jetty-util-7.6.16.v20140903.jar:7.6.16.v20140903]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [na:1.7.0_09-icedtea]
```

Interestingly, native git seems to have no issues with these repositories. I can still clone them, and their history as shown by `git log` seems intact. If I create a local copy with `git clone --bare` and set that as my remote, I can push to this local copy successfully.

`git fsck` showed two dangling commits and a dangling tag, which disappeared after a `git gc`. However, this did not fix the problem.

I've tried using `git push --no-thin`, based on e.g. [git unpack error on push to gerrit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16586642/git-unpack-error-on-push-to-gerrit), but got the same error as above.

I've also tried creating a new, empty repository on the SCM Manager side, and setting it as the remote for a local copy of a problematic repo. The initial push seems to succeed, but any further pushes to the new repository result in the same error.

Since local pushes using native git still work, it seems to me that these repositories should be salvageable. But I'm at a loss as to how to proceed. Any ideas on either fixing these repositories or salvaging as much of their history as possible would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like a jgit bug, which is the library SCM-Manager make usage of. Are you using the latest version of SCM-Manager?

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem and fixed it by adding a new commit (comitting an additional dot in a comment :) ).

my error message:

```
C:\Users\313373\Documents\Git\myproj>git push
Username for 'xyz': 313373
Password for 'xyz':
Enumerating objects: 85, done.
Counting objects: 100% (84/84), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (34/34), done.
Writing objects: 100% (40/40), 4.65 KiB | 153.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 40 (delta 14), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: remote unpack failed: error Short read of block.
To https://remoteurl......redacted
 ! [remote rejected]   develop -> develop (n/a (unpacker error))
error: failed to push some refs to REPONAME
```

Comment: I hate that this works. Because it works, but it doesn't solve the problem with SCM Manager,

Comment: Yes, but i wasn't able to identify details on the issue nor was I able to reproduce it. If you have logs maybe it's possible to file a bug report.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem  and for me I was pushing a relay big  file.
ignoring this file soled my problem.